# "unable to append to .git/logs/refs/heads/master" when commiting

Tags: git

I've been having some strange errors lately. I have a working install of Git, but this is my shell output when committing changes:

```
$ git commit -m 'Removing crap'
error: unable to append to .git/logs/refs/heads/master
fatal: cannot update HEAD ref
```

Comment: What does `git fsck` show you?

Comment: dangling commit 89e268b736b233ac1c7778b20f0541932c387096
dangling commit ee24220d0b6fbc31a9e07a58993b8f2360afa216
dangling commit ff24fe8f928b7c5dc41376c8fc5ec8cdcf7cbd20
dangling commit af36717779105b7994e544766d4a6e85ebbf8e27
dangling commit f737506211dd995e50df0a10d189beca44a7c385

Comment: So, no major errors then? That means it's *probably not* a repository integrity problem.

Comment: So, do you have any idea what's causing it?

Comment: I'm afraid not, sorry. You might try using `strace` to see if you can identify the failing system call.

Comment: When I ran VS Code with Administrator rights it worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check the user and permission on `.git/logs/refs/heads/master`

This should might fix it it, at least on a unix machine:

```
sudo chown -Rc $UID .git/
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure I have read+write permissions. I opened it in pico, and I was able to write text to it.

Answer (score 2):

```
chmod 766 .git/logs/HEAD
```

worked for me

Answer (score 0):

The ownership can get messed up if you made changes as another user, e.g. root and then tried to push/pull etc. The sudo chown -Rc $UID .git/ fixed it for me too. Make sure that if you have nested .git folders, you make this change in the appropriate repo of your project.