# About fatal: could not open '.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG': Permission denied

Tags: git, bash, permission-denied

I am having the same problem like:

[this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917094/fatal-could-not-open-git-commit-editmsg-permission-denied)

when I tried the given answer:

```
chown --recursive $(id -u) .
```

in my git bash, and after I tried to commit I still have the problem. If I run:

```
chown --recursive $(id -u)
```

(Notice that the dot is not there) I got the following message:

```
chown: missing operand after '197609'
```

What does it mean? That the missing operand is the dot?

Why "chown --recursive $(id -u) ." is not solving the problem? What other things can I do?

Thanks for your help

Comment: What does `id` output ? What does `ls -l .git/COMMIT_EDITMSG` output in the repository with that file?

Comment: id does: `uid=197609(DJH) gid=197121 groups=197121` and ls -l .git/COMMIT_EDITMSG : `-r--r--r-- 1 DJH 197121 22 sept. 17 10:37 .git/COMMIT_EDITMSG`

Comment: it does: `drwxr-xr-x 1 DJH 197121 0 oct. 26 17:34 .git/`

Comment: And you are using `git` from the command line or from some graphical/other client when this happens?

Comment: I was using tortoisegit but I have the same problem when I use git bash

Comment: If you try to open that file with notepad or some other Windows application does it work?

Comment: Yes I can open the  file: COMMIT_EDITMSG with notepad++

Comment: And write to it? Does that change the permissions on it or the directory?

Comment: Have you tried _all_ the proposed solutions in the linked answer?

Comment: Yes, all except the one about YandexDisk, since I do not use that.

Comment: No, I cannot write in the file.

Comment: When I delete the COMMIT_EDITMSG file, it leads me to the following error [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10058155/unable-to-append-to-git-logs-refs-heads-master-when-commiting) but the given solutions does not work either.

Comment: Do you also applied command given in comments? (`chmod -R u+x .git`)

Comment: I have tried the command `chmod -R u+x .git`